# How to keep certain parts of a string in R

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

I have a data set with individuals and their birth countries. However, some of the people were born in a time where Yugoslavia, Austrian Empire, Prussia etc., existed, so in the columns values, the current country is in brackets. How can I keep only the country in the brackets so that I can later group my data by country?

```
Person          Birth Country
 Nick         Prussia (Germany)
 Mike             Germany
 Maria            Canada
 Mark          Russian Empire (Poland)         
 Sven             Germany
 Jarek            Poland
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract the characters that are not `)` after a `(` as a capture group and in the replacement specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df1$Country <- sub(".*\\(([^)]+)\\).*", "\\1", df1$`Birth Country`)
df1$Country
#[1] "Germany" "Germany" "Canada"  "Poland"  "Germany" "Poland"
```

The pattern we are matching is `.*` (any character) followed by a literal `(` (escape -`\\(` - as it is a metacharacter),  then capture the characters as a group (`(...)`) that are not a `)` (`[^)]+`), followed by `)` (`\\)`) and any other characters (`.*`)

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Person = c("Nick", "Mike", "Maria", "Mark", "Sven", 
"Jarek"), `Birth Country` = c("Prussia (Germany)", "Germany", 
"Canada", "Russian Empire (Poland)", "Germany", "Poland")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: This works, thanks Akrun! Do you mind maybe providing a little explanation to how that works please?

Comment: @NickA thanks, I added some description.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything until opening brackets and a closing bracket (if they exist) :

```
gsub('.*\\(|\\)', '', df$Birth_Country)
#[1] "Germany" "Germany" "Canada"  "Poland"  "Germany" "Poland"
```